# How to validate X-PLIVO-SIGNATURE

Tags: plivo

We are using plivo to send/receive SMS messages. We have a webhook configured to receive the messages sent by a customer. We want to validate if the request infact originated from plivo. Can anyone please tell me how to validate using the auth token we have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Plivo documentation here](https://www.plivo.com/docs/sms/getting-started/advanced/signature-validation/) has a section about how to verify the signature of an incoming webhook request (it's using HMAC).

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit tricky. There is an error in Plivo documentation. Or, you could see it as a bug in their implementation.

If you are using Ruby the code that you'll need, as explained by the documentation is:

```
Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest("SHA256", "AUTH_TOKEN", "YOUR_CALLBACK_URL/REQUEST_HEADER_X-Plivo-Signature-V2-Nonce"))
```

But, this never works. You never get a match the hash with the x-plivo-signature-v2, right?
I've also tried to use the Auth Key, instead of Auth Token. And every combination of those fields.

To make it work you must change your code to this version:

```
Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest("SHA256", "AUTH_TOKEN", "YOUR_CALLBACK_URLREQUEST_HEADER_X-Plivo-Signature-V2-Nonce"))
```

Have you noticed the difference?
**Yep! Drop the slash between your callback URL and X-Plivo-Signature-V2-Nonce.**

I verified it at the current implementation of [Plivo SDK(4.3.2)](https://github.com/plivo/plivo-ruby/blob/v4.3.2/lib/plivo/utils.rb#L106)

By the way, if you're insecure about where to find your AUTH_TOKEN and YOUR_CALLBACK_URL

AUTH_TOKEN: [image]

YOUR_CALLBACK_URL: [image]

Comment: I also believe this is mainly caused by *my callback URL* doesn't end with a '/'